# Import cypress data to EHR for QRDA category 1(CQM - capture and export) meaningful use

Tags: c#, xml, ccd, c-cda

I am working on Clinical Quality Measures – Capture and Export. 
Which implies "Every CQM, EHR technology must be able to electronically record all of the required data" and then generate files in QRDA format. I have review many document but no one provided clarification.

For QRDA Cat-1 we are provided with patient data package from Cypress(Html for Manual and XMl for automatic) to enter into EMR. But this data package contains 56 patient files.

**Question:**

1. Do we need to import all (56) patient data files for Category -1?
2. Do we need to capture all information of every file, means patient medication info, lab test info. etc. Or only info that we need to calculate a CQM?
3. Is there any dll or somthing like which can be used in .net c# to read patient data XML files Or we need to do it manually (read xml using Xml reader and add data to EHR)?

Please suggest any relevant information regarding this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: HI. Have you been able to find answers to these questions? If not I believe I can help.

Comment: HI @SixOThree, I found some detail about importing cypress data. But still i am confused a little bit. It'll be great if you can help :). I am creating a parser to read xml patient data files for importing. Please suggest something; how to prevent duplicate patient importing ?

Comment: Also there seems to be some difference in Html and XML file data.I checked "0_AMI_ADULT_A.html" is showing 2 encounter but "0_AMI_ADULT_A.xml" showing 6 encounter (as Entry node). Please clarify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you are planning to certify on every measure you will need to import all of the patients. But tests generated in Cypress with fewer measures will have fewer patients. Also the tests will randomize the patients somewhat where the patients you listed sound like they're straight from the test deck.
2. You don't necessarily need to capture all of the information because Cypress is not going to verify all of the information. The output files only need to have the data listed in the Data Criteria sections of the measure you are calculating.
3. Not sure if this is within the rules of Stack Overflow. But you did ask and I am one of the authors of CQMsolution - a tool that reads cypress data patient data in XML format and performs measure calculations. It is a retail product but it does everything needed to calculate CQMs. We also offer consulting. Web site in my contact info page. We created it because there was a distinct lack of products that did this. It is written in C#.

Comment: Thank you @SixOThree, this is valuable.